# How to style by date monthly ranges QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

So I have mypointtable with columns id, mydate and geom and I need to style it according to the months in the date column

For example:

```
id | mydate
1  | 2019-11-01
2  | 2019-11-15
3  | 2019-11-28
4  | 2019-12-03
5  | 2020-01-01
```

I've tried using `month(age(mydate, now()))  <=1`

But besides being a bit slow, it just takes all the features from now and 30 days from now. So wrongly capturing ids 2,3 and 4

Intended result is to capture all features in November, so ids 1, 2 and 3 but not 4

I tried a solution for this month only which is `month(mydate) - month(now()) = 0 and year(mydate) - year(now()) = 0`. But the problem with this approach is that while it does work for this month, it does not work for December.

How to create a solution to style current month and the next 5 months?

By next 5 months I mean

- style for current month (november at the moment)
- style for next month (december at the moment)
- style for in 2 months (january at the moment)
- style for in 3 months (feb at the moment)
- style for in 4 months (mar at the moment)
- style for in 5 months (apr at the moment)
- style for anything after 5 months months (may onwards)

Comment: Does your date-column include dates from different years, and if so, should they be styled identical or different?

Comment: @Erik Yes, that's why I'm saying my 2nd attempt doesn't work for December. I'm rewriting it to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not suggest using the date functions, because the distance from e.g. `2019-10-28` to `2019-11-1` would be `0` where you expect `1`. Instead access the year and month via `substr` function and calculate the distance in months say from 10/2019 onwords. The following Expression does the trick:

```
(to_int(substr("my_date", 0, 4)) - 2019) * 12 + (to_int(substr("my_date", 6, 2)) - 10)
```

For testing purposes I created a dataset and a virtual field as follows:

[image]

result:

[image]

Then I use a categorized renderer like this:

[image]

resulting in

[image]

Comment: I had to revisit this and it did work, but doesn't work in 2020 anymore

Answer (score 2):

this expression calculates the difference in months from now on and a date in the future

```
if(
year(now()) = year("my_date"), 
month("my_date") - month(now()), 
month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))
)
```

[image]

To style you can use a rule-based style using
 6 rules:

- current month: `if(year(now()) = year("my_date"), month("my_date") - month(now()), month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))) = 0`
- next month: `if(year(now()) = year("my_date"), month("my_date") - month(now()), month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))) = 1`
- second next month: `if(year(now()) = year("my_date"), month("my_date") - month(now()), month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))) = 2`
- third next month: `if(year(now()) = year("my_date"), month("my_date") - month(now()), month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))) = 3`
- forth next month: `if(year(now()) = year("my_date"), month("my_date") - month(now()), month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))) = 4`
- fifth next month: `if(year(now()) = year("my_date"), month("my_date") - month(now()), month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))) = 5`
- beyond 5 months: `if(year(now()) = year("my_date"), month("my_date") - month(now()), month("my_date") - month(now()) + (12 * (year("my_date") - year(now())))) > 5`

Comment: Insert the modulo operator: `(month(now()+x)%12` gives the correct month in the next year, which can be compared to the `mydate`-column.

Comment: sorry @Erik, I just changed my answer based on your previous answer

Comment: This is exactly how i have it in the OP giving me wrong dates from october..

Comment: @PieterB then maybe change it back, using the modulo-operator - since OP says it doesn't work as intended this way.

Comment: @Erik, I was struggling with the modulo operator, but I found another sollution

Answer (score 0):

For map styling proposes (symbology-> graduated) try this: `concat(year("mydate"), '-', lpad(month("mydate"),'2','0'))`. Output has yyyy-MM format. The series of strings this expression makes, preserves a meaningful (i.e. chronological) order. Alternatively, you can create a virtual field (e.g. virtual_1) by using the same expression, so you can categorize your dataset by month based on the "virtual_1" field (symbology-> categorized or easy filtering etc).  If you also want to count records per month, create another virtual layer (e.g. virtual_2) with this expression: `count(mydate, group_by:= virtual_1)`